# Angular ng-style for ::after

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-style

I am designing a dynamic hr (horizonatal) rule.

In my Style sheet

```
hr.my-hr:after{
   content:'Generic'
}
```

In my template

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['Adam', 'Collin', 'David']">
<hr class="my-hr" ng-style="{'content':name}">
```

But how do i dynamically change the content in the template when using ng-repeat ????

Comment: why not think of changing array itself?

Comment: Can you just give an example ??

Comment: Why not just use `ng-class` and dynamically add and remove the class `my-hr`? EDIT: You can only use pseudo elements in a selector not inline. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) All `ng-style` does is add inline styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `ng-style` does is add inline styles. However you want to add a psuedo element `::after`. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

> You can use only one pseudo-element in a selector. It must appear after the simple selectors in the statement.

So inferred from that you can't use them inline, which sadly means `ng-style` can't do what your after.

However if your `::after` is defined in a stylesheet you can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to dynamically add that style.

So

```
<hr ng-class="{'my-hr': <some condition to evaluate>}" />
```

Most cases that will suffice. However it looks like to want to dynamically set the `content` of `::after`. So for that i can only imagine two options.

If you just want to simply add the string value use databinding

```
<hr />
{{name}}
```

However if you want extra styling on that string create a small directive as a re-usable widget may be the better option.