# apply background to element:after dynamically with ngStyle

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, interpolation

I'm applying a background to a div like so:

```
<div class="bgimg">test</div>

.bgimg {
  padding-top: 10px;
  &::after {
    background: url('/assets/img/test.png') no-repeat center center;
  }
}
```

The path to the image is dynamic and stored in the component:

```
export class MyComponent {

  myImage: string = "/assets/img/test.png";
```

So to my div element I want to apply an ngStyle but I don't know how to specify :after

```
<div
  [ngStyle]="background: url('{myImage}') no-repeat center center;">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: Don't remember how to exactly. Try something like `<div #el>`. In component: `el:ElementRef`. `change(){el.style = ????}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-style for ::after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356952/angular-ng-style-for-after)

Comment: @QuentinLaillé that question is for AngularJS while this one is for Angular2+

Comment: Do you have some reason for not using an extra HTML element (`div` or `img`) instead of the `::after` clause?

Comment: @JánHalaša yes, it's to position an image absolutely. It overflows the parent and I cannot hide it.

Comment: @JánHalaša: my only solution was move the background to a div like you said. I couldn't do it at firstbut now it's ok. I guess I'll delete the question?

Comment: The correct syntax for ngStyle should be <div [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + myImage + ') no-repeat center center'}"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `::after` pseudo class you are not applying the background to either the parent `div` or any other element. It's not clear why you want to use `::after` to show a background.

1. You need to include `ng-style` such as: `<div ng-style="bgimg">test</div>` so that Angular can reference the element.
2. Once you have that, you can call `bgimg={'background-image':'url(myImage)'}` and it will apply the background to the referenced element.

For more information, take a look at this [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and this [example code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fl6cFSN4C9eD4QQpU1rS?p=preview) you can play with. I hope this helps, but this is my first answer on StackOverflow so bear with me!

Comment: The only solution was to move the background to a div as there's no solution to dynamically style an :after. I'll accept your answer anyway.