# Change after property in ng-style without using ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So I'm trying to create a *directive* for a some kind of stepper arrow progress bar.

Please see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/wrmVwY) to understand what I'm talking about. (Note that i wrote the params in the function scope to have an easier read).

The problem I am facing now, is that I wanna pass the colors **as param** to my directive and I need to apply the colors to both the class and the :after property.

I use that sample to change the background-color of the block-head class, using ng-style. The ng-class I use is to get plain start and end.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements"
 class="block-head"
 ng-class="{'block-head-first': $first, 'block-head-last': $last}"
 ng-style="{'width' : selectedKey === element.key ? 'calc(100% - ' + 
 widthCalc + 'px)' : '',
 'background-color': getColor($index)}">
```

```
$scope.widthCalc = ($scope.elements.length - 1) * 26
$scope.getColor = function($index) {
    if ($scope.elements[$index].key === $scope.selectedKey)
      return $scope.colors['current']
    if ($scope.elements[$index].key < $scope.selectedKey)
      return $scope.colors['success']
    if ($scope.elements[$index].key > $scope.selectedKey)
      return $scope.colors['disable']
}
```

Below is the sample of code I wanna change with ng-style (I set it to lightblue so you understand visually what i'm trying to change).

```
.block-head:after {
  color: lightblue;
```

I thought of two potential fixes but I have no idea on how to do them. First would be to 'heritate' the color value from the parent in background-color in pure css (not even sure that it is possible ?). Second would be to create classes in my js code and use those classes using ng-class.

All the related questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498920/how-to-change-style-for-before-after-in-angular), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356952/angular-ng-style-for-after)) always advice to use ng-class, but I see no obvious fix with it on my case.

Comment: You can use "inherit" as a CSS value for background-color or color, the one catch being that the parent element needs the same property/color you want set.

Comment: The problem of that is I use the color attribute in the :after, meaning that I'd have to change the color attribute in the main class, meaning that my span text wouldn't be visible (would be the same color as the background)

Comment: Never mind I could just use another class for the span color indeed ... That was obvious I wonder why i got stuck on this but thanks :)